# Creating a single variable with multiple categories in R

Tags: r

I am working with a survey that asks questions based on the answer to previous questions. I need to create a single variable with multiple categories.

An example:

```
(1) Do you have a bank account? Yes/No
(2) If yes: How many bank accounts do you have, <5 or >5?
(3) If >5: what is the total value? If <5, what is the value of account 1 thru 5?
```

I need to create one variable that is ‘total value bank account’, with multiple categories:

```
Yes <5_value1

Yes <5_value2

Yes <5_value3

Yes <5_value4

Yes <5_value5

Yes >5_total_value

No
```

How can I do this in R?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. What do you mean by single variable with multiple categories? You can define a list with multiple elements, that can be of different type, if that is what you want. For conditional arguments you would just use `if ... else` statements.

Comment: Hi, my variable has multiple categories as in a person can have either 1 thru 5 bank accounts with reported values for each account or >5 with a reported total value or no bank account woth a 0 value. My end goal is to perform missing value analysis (a significant amount of people did not know their bank account balance) using MissMDA, and I need to seperate between those truly missing values and missing values because the person was simply not asked the question. I need therefore to create a single variable with multiple categories I believe.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Data**

You did not tell us how your raw data looks like, so I assume it is in a data frame as follows:

```
(my_data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, c(3, 1, 1)),
                      has.bank.account = rep(c("yes", "no"), c(4, 1)),
                      nr.of.accounts   = rep(c(3, 6, NA), c(3, 1, 1)),
                      amount           = c(1000 * 1:3, 10000, NA)))

#   id has.bank.account nr.of.accounts amount
# 1  1              yes              3   1000
# 2  1              yes              3   2000
# 3  1              yes              3   3000
# 4  2              yes              6  10000
# 5  3               no             NA     NA
```

**Code**

Then you can use `ifelse` to create a new variable:

```
with(my_data, 
     ifelse(has.bank.account == "no", 
            "no", 
            paste0("Yes ", 
                   ifelse(nr.of.accounts > 5, ">5_", "<=5_"), 
                   amount
                   )
           )
    )

# [1] "Yes <=5_1000" "Yes <=5_2000" "Yes <=5_3000" "Yes >5_10000" "no"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Excuse that I did not explain what the data looks like. It actually looks as you said, but if a person has 3 accounts, they will be asked for the balance on account 1-3 separately. Only if a person has >5 accounts, the total balance will be asked. 

Edit: I can of course simply add up the individual balances, and arrive at your dataframe. So this is a good solution thank you!

Comment: Well, that is what I'd try to simulate in my sample data. Column `id` differentiates the persons. So person with `id=1` gave actually 3 answers.

Comment: Exactly. In the end I want to impute the total balance, as many people know for example the balance on their first two accounts but not on their third. I don't know how to use missMDA or mice in that case, but I guess I can just total it out and then give a missing value to the total if one of the balances is missing. That would ignore some of the data that I do have (their first two balances), but I do not know how else to make the package work.